# How i find which event is working on window.onbeforeunload?

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

How i find which event is working on window.onbeforeunload? for example refresh, back, browser close etc

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
    alert('here i need to show which event is working')
    return "";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to identify onbeforeunload was caused by clicking close button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757942/how-to-identify-onbeforeunload-was-caused-by-clicking-close-button)

Comment: Still, that question was asked quite a long time ago, perhaps something has changed since. )